# App Center - Android release crash on startup

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

Issue happens while deploying a React-Native app via App Center - no crash when doing `gradlew assembleRelease` locally.
IOS build, deploy and running and build successfully.
In Android - Build passed successfully but when Im installing the app it crashes on startup.

When I check logcat I see the below error - Its seems like the version is a debug version (metro mentioned) but Im not sure.

What could be the issue?

> 2021-11-09 08:54:36.227 21255-21326/? E/unknown:ReactNative:
> ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext: mJSIModulePackage null
> 2021-11-09 08:54:36.227 898-898/? E/libc: Access denied finding
> property "ro.hardware.fp.fod" 2021-11-09 08:54:36.228 898-898/?
> E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.fp.sideCap"
> 2021-11-09 08:54:36.229 21255-21326/?
> E/unknown:DisabledDevSupportManager: Caught exception
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or
> that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for
> release.
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native
> Method)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:258)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
>
> ```
> --------- beginning of crash 2021-11-09 08:54:36.229 21255-21326/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
> Process: com.toluna.webservice, PID: 21255
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or
> ```
>
> that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for
> release.
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native
> Method)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:258)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved it.
It seems this is a react-native 0.63.3 issue and not an App Center issue.

When doing the follow:

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleRelease // or other variant
```

This issue is that Build passed successfully but the index.android.bundle file is not created inside the apk.

to check that you can do:

```
1. unzip [APK_FILE] -d [directory] 
2. Go to assets directory and look for index.android.bundle file.
```

Only after running again:

```
gradlew assembleRelease // or other variant
```

we get the index.android.bundle file inside the apk

Its seems there is a tasks order issue - was solved with this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29398#issuecomment-724350920)

by adding to the app/build.gradle:

```
// Fix for bundle not getting included in APK or AAB with android gradle plugin 4+
// Seems like there's a React-Native bug - task ordering issue and the assets get computed before the bundle is copied
// This forces the copy task to run before merge resources
// This should be fixed and removed starting with RN 0.63.4.
// Relevant thread: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29398#issuecomment-724350920
project.afterEvaluate {
  def isAndroidLibrary = plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")
  def variants = isAndroidLibrary ? android.libraryVariants : android.applicationVariants
  variants.all { def variant ->
    def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
    def mergeResourcesTask = tasks.findByName("merge${targetName}Resources")
    def assetsCopyTask = tasks.findByName("copy${targetName}BundledJs")
    mergeResourcesTask.dependsOn(assetsCopyTask)
    logger.warn("Making task ${mergeResourcesTask} depend on ${assetsCopyTask}")
  }
}
```